# C programming - opening from a specific windows directory

Tags: c, fopen

I fairly new to the C programming language.  I am writing a program that will eventually read through mp3 files from a user inputted directory, and sort the mp3's into artist/album folders by utilizing the metadata in the id3's.  I am accessing the user's directory using the system() function call, and generating a .txt file containing all of the mp3's in that directory.  However I am running into problems when trying to access the first mp3 file.  I am building the mp3 file's path, but the file will not open.  The file DOES open when I hard code the path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct FILE_head
{
  char file_id[3];
  char version[2];
  char flags;
  char size[4];
};

int main()
{
  //declare vars
  char cd[1200];
  char mp3[200];
  char dir[1000];
  char mp3_path[1200];
  FILE *list_file;
  FILE *mp3_file;
  struct FILE_head id3;
  char dir_cmd[1300] = "dir ";
  char find_cmd[100] = "/b | find \".mp3\" > \"mp3List.txt\"";
  int dir_len;
  int amt_read;

  //main code

  while(1)
  {
    cd[0]='c'; 
    cd[1]='d';
    cd[2]=' ';
    cd[3]='\0';

    printf("Enter the directory where mp3's are located:");
    scanf("%s", dir);
    strcat(cd, dir);
    if(system(cd) == 0) //if directory is valid, break.  otherwise stay in loop/reprompt
        break;
    printf("Valid directory Ex--> c:\\users\\username\\music\n");
  }

  //build cmd statement
  strcat(dir_cmd, dir);
  strcat(dir_cmd, find_cmd);
  system(dir_cmd);

  dir_len = strlen(dir);
  strcpy(mp3_path, dir);
  printf("%s\n", mp3_path);

  list_file = fopen("mp3List.txt", "rb");
  if(list_file != NULL)
  {
    while(fgets(mp3, sizeof(mp3), list_file))
    {
      printf("%s", mp3);
      strcat(mp3_path, mp3);
      printf("%s\n", mp3_path);
      mp3_path[strlen(mp3_path)-1] = '\0';
      mp3_file = fopen(mp3_path, "rb");
      if(mp3_file != NULL)
      {
        printf("in this loop");
        fread(&id3, sizeof(id3), 1, mp3_file);
        printf("%s\n", id3.file_id);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is my first time posting, so if any more information would be helpful please let me know.  I realize there might be "better" ways to access directories, but I don't want to use any functions that are not in the **C** std lib.

This is my output:

> C:\Users\Mitchell\Projects>mp3sort.exe Enter the directory where mp3's
>   are located:c:\users\mitchell\projects\music_test\
>   c:\users\mitchell\projects\music_test\ 01 - Time to Pretend.mp3
>   c:\users\mitchell\projects\music_test\01 - Time to Pretend.mp3
>
> 01-all_that_remains-this_calling.mp3
>   01-all_that_remains-this_calling.mp3t\01 - Time to Pretend.mp3
>
> 07 Billy Joel - Everybody Loves You Now.mp3 07 Billy Joel - Everybody
>   Loves You Now.mp3Time to Pretend.mp3
>
> Tears for the Sheep.mp3 Tears for the Sheep.mp3dy Loves You
>   Now.mp3Time to Pretend.mp3
>
> C:\Users\Mitchell\Projects>

I know that my current build for the all the files after the first isn't correct, but I was just focused on getting the first mp3_path to work.  I removed the newline by: `mp3_path[strlen(mp3_path)-1] = '\0';`

Comment: Most probably there is some bug in the creation of the path. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I have been using printf to check mp3_path. I will try a debugger right now though.

Comment: What's output of your program?

Comment: I updated my question with my output.  The build for the first path appears to be correct (I realize that my paths for the latter files are all messed up as of right now).

Comment: You would do better by using FindFirstFile/FindNextFile instead of using system to create the file list. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`system()` executes provided command in subprocess. When you do `system ("cd somedir")`, `cd somedir` is executed in child process, thus working directory of your process remains unaltered.

If you want to change your process working directory, use [`chdir()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235420.aspx) (or [`_chdir()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx), alternatively [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to use Windows API) function.

Alternatively, you can avoid changing working directory by prepending directory to file names.

Comment: What is chdir? If you are going to use strange non-standard functions, it is probably a better idea to use the Win API directly.

Comment: @Lundin I added relevant links to MSDN to my answer.

Comment: Alternative documentation: [POSIX `chdir` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html).

Comment: I believe that SetCurrentDirectory is a c++ function? I want to try to stick strictly to C

Comment: All of those functions are C functions, albeit `SetCurrentDirectory` is specific to Windows. `chdir` is part of POSIX standard (but not C standard).

Comment: I will consider using SetCurrentDirectory.  However this doesn't really answer my question.  I was aware that my system("cd somedir") wasn't changing my working directory, I was doing this to check for a valid directory.  I still don't understand why I cannot open the mp3 file when I build the path, but I can when I hardcode it.